# Upgrade error .net 1 winforms application

Tags: .net, winforms, upgrade

I have an ld application written in .NET 1.1 which I try to upgrade to .NET 3.5.
The VsStudio conversion is all fine, and after the upgrade I can run the application without any problems. However, since the fonts are another the text won't fit inside the controls.
And that's where my trouble start, because as soon as I change anything, be it the size of a control or the size of any font, after a build the designer stops working with that form, hides it and display an error:

```
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object     value)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

Then, when I try to run the application, it won't load those forms at all, I only get an error.
I'm not that comfortable with .NET so any hint on what might be the error would be helpful, thanks and regards!

Comment: Are you able to provide the message that goes along with that error?  If you run this in via the Visual Studio debugger with exceptions turned on, do you get any indication as to which property is being set when this exception occurs?  Something is going on in the 'set' portion of one of your properties and you will need to provide some code in order for anyone to assist debugging this.

Comment: Hi and thanks, its just an ordinary "unhandled exception" msgbox. It seem it doesn't matter which property on the form that's being set. It all works until I change something, whatever, and then the designer crash and it won't run. I wonder if some file somewhere might be write-protected, though I removed it from the top folder

Comment: That is a stacktrace, not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to work when I set the "DesignerSerializationVisibility" attribute on some of the properties. This prevent the Designer from crashing and I was able to build and run my application

Comment: This is a bandage that doesn't address the real issue.

Comment: Utilizing that attribute is preventing the property from being accessed by the designer, thus avoiding the error, but I would worry that accessing the property at runtime may result in the same error. Additionally, you may be losing persistence of settings that would otherwise be written to the designer generated files.

Comment: That doesn't sound to good. The application do work though, but I guess that might get odd errors in the future

Answer (score 0):

In Framework 1.0 in resx file the empty value was presented using < value/> and from 2.0 forward was changed into < value>< /value>.
Edit the resx before change into the designer from < value /> to < value >< /value> and it works.

Comment: Thanks for answering, sorry but I'm not all with you there? Should I edit the resx files by hand and change some values?

Comment: I had the same issue and the solution was to edit manually the files.

Comment: Ok, you changed "using" into?